# How to remove API level styles higher than my API level used?

Tags: android, android-studio

All these resources, how can I stop Android Studio from adding them to the build? And where do they even come from?

I've recently downgraded my project because I intend to make an app for Honeycomb (I expect my audience to use relatively old phones). But after I did that, I got all these errors and I've no idea how to stop Gradle from adding them to the build.

[image]

Comment: Check the included files in each of you class files.  Android Studio likes to add them for you.

Comment: Why not set the minimum API level to whatever you want to support, but keep the target API level at 25 (or whatever is most recent)? Then you're not excluding anyone.

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: @ABoschman Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I stop Android Studio from adding them to the build?

Technically speaking, you get rid of the code that is trying to add them.

Practically speaking, they are most likely serving a purpose for you, and that your problem is that you changed the `compileSdkVersion` to too low of a value.

> And where do they even come from?

Libraries, most likely.

> I've recently downgraded my project because I intend to make an app for Honeycomb

My guess is that you changed your `compileSdkVersion`. Change it back. Your `minSdkVersion` needs to be low enough to support your older devices; your `compileSdkVersion` needs to be high enough to support all of your code. Typically, `compileSdkVersion` is set to a recent version (e.g., 25 at the moment).

> I intend to make an app for Honeycomb (I expect my audience to use relatively old phones)

Honeycomb (Android 3.x) was never used on phones.

Comment: Oh, well then I guess I'm aiming for Jelly Bean instead.

Comment: @AllFriend Have a look at the distribution of Android versions [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). You probably want API level 15, or Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: I'm making a language learning app which targets refugees from Syria and Afghanistan, and don't expect them to change phone as often as regular westerners. Currently I myself use Jelly Bean, and I don't want to go any later than that. I think I'm already excluding a lot of people with old smartphones.

Comment: @AllFriend: Set your `minSdkVersion` to be 14 or 15 for Jelly Bean. Pretty much all API Level 14 (Android 4.0) devices should have been upgraded to API Level 15 (Android 4.0.3), so I would use 15. Set your `compileSdkVersion` to be 25, or at worst, ensure that it matches the major version of any `com.android.support` library that you are using. So, for example, if your module's `build.gradle` file is pulling in `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0`, set your `compileSdkVersion` to 25, to match the major version (25) in the library version (25.1.0).